# Is there a keyboard shortcut for a mouse click?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sap

I've been using the program SAP for awhile to write reports and the program has a lot of tedious boxes to tick and pages to go through. One way to speed up the process is using the keyboard to do everything. The only thing I can't manage to workout is how to check a tickbox/checkbox using the keyboard only. I'm able to highlight the box using the 'tab' button but hitting 'enter' completes the entire page, without ticking the checkbox.
Is there a way to replicate the mouseclick without using 'enter' and completing the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `spacebar` key can be used to tick/untick box.

Note: This may depends on the application as pressing space may ends up scrolling your screen. But for now this is your best bet.

Comment: I logged on and gave this a try - it worked! I swear I had already 'spacebar'...
Thanks for your help!!